# How to grab first word of string and convert it to int? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to grab first word in string and I need to convert it to integer.
How to do this using jQuery?

**example** : "223 Lorem Ipsum Dolor"

I need "**223**" and it must be converted into **integer**...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can split a string based on any character (like a space), then pass the first index to `parseInt`

```
var str = "223 lorem";
var num = parseInt(str.split(' ')[0], 10);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kf5Kj/1/)

Note that `parseInt` takes a second parameter, which is the radix.  If you leave that off, and try to parse a number with a leading zero, like `09`, it'll assume you're in base 8, and will return 0, since `09` isn't a valid base-8 value.

---

Or, as John points out, using the unary `+` operator is a nifty way to convert a string to a number:

```
var str = "223 lorem";
var num = +str.split(' ')[0];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kf5Kj/2/)

Comment: +1, only thing I would recommend is passing `10` as second param to `parseInt`, just good practice IMO.

Comment: @Chad - I should have known better - I've been burned by that before

Comment: @Bcee : Just FYI, the method presented above is pure Javascript since your question has nothing to do with jQuery. I'm understanding you are using jQuery in your project/homework whatever it is but I suggest you learn Javascript. jQuery doesn't touch on topics listed in your question.

Comment: @kubarium - this comment belongs on the question, not the answer :)

Comment: Also a shortcut to parsing ANY (not just strings) data type to an integer is (+).  Ex. `+'1234' === 1234` and `+true === 1`

Comment: More unary goodness, `~~` to floor that sucker to an integer :)

Comment: @John - now that I did *not* know.  COOL.  I assume the bitwise not is converting the decimal value to an integer, then doing its thing?  So ~2.2 is the same as ~2, and so ~~2.2 will get you back to 2?

Comment: @Adam There's no real need to split the string and get the first element of the returned array.
It will work just as good if you just pass the string to parseInt since it will keep rendering numbers until it finds characters which are non numeral and stop there.
so this will do the trick

var num = parseInt( str, 10 );

Comment: @PM5544 - you're absolutely right.  The benefit of the above though is that it's easily chaneable if OP later wants the second, or third word to be converted

Comment: @Adam Yes, for the most part it's pretty crazy that it works out to a flooring operation :)  James Padolsey explains it best [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/).

Comment: Note that all these convert any non-number to NaN (which, as you can try in the jsfiddle's, is a number!)

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
var str = "223 Lorem Ipsum Dolor";
str = $.trim(str).split(" ");
var num = parseInt(str[0], 10);
```

Comment: +1, but like my original answer, you need a radix parameter in your parseInt :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use something like:

```
var str = "223 Lorem Ipsum Dolor";
var matches = str.match(/(\d+)/);
result = parseInt(matches[0]);
```

Maybe you'll want to wse some nots before the \d+

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function getFirstNumber(str) {
  var matched = str.match(/^\d+/);
  if(matched) {
    return +matched[0]; // Get matched number (as string) and type cast to Number.
  }

  console.error("first word is not a number: '" + str + "'.");
  return -1;
};

var str = "223 lorem";

getFirstNumber(str);
```