# Strip rest of value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let's assume that I retrieve the page title using javascript, and the value is something like

`FrontPage | Website.com`

I need only the first word of this, so like `FrontPage` without **any** whitespace. I know how to do this with PHP, but how would I do it with javascript?

I need it for this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("[title='"' + strippedtitle + '"']").addClass("valittu");
});
```

Comment: See 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039454/how-to-grab-first-word-of-string-and-convert-it-to-int-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/iremin/1/edit)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var title1 = "FrontPage | Website.com";

    var strippedtitle = $.trim(title1.split('|')[0]);

    alert(strippedtitle);   
 });
```

Comment: But for some reason, it won't work. I tried moving the vars inside document ready, and replaced addClass with alert, and nothing happened. I'll make a fiddle about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method.

```
var str = 'FrontPage | Website.com';
var whatYouNeed = str.split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `split`,

```
var str = 'FrontPage | Website.com';     
var firstWord = str.split(" ")[0].replace(/\s/g,'');
```